# If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ prove that $(a^2,b^2)=1$ or $2$.

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Hello I have got the answer for question ie. if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ prove $(a+b,a-b)= 1$ or $2$
But I want to find answer for, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ prove $(a^2,b^2)=1$ or $2$

Comment: if $(a,b)=1$, then $(a^2,b^2)=1$

Comment: if GCD(a,b) = 1 the two number are not both even. How is it possible that $a^2$ and $b^2$  are both even?

Answer (score 3):

If $ua+vb=1$, then
$$1^2=(ua+vb)^2=u^2a^2+2uvab+v^2b^2 $$
and
$$ub\cdot a^2+va\cdot b^2=ab,$$
hence
$$(u^2-2u^2vb)a^2+(v^2-2uv^2a)b^2=1 $$

Comment: Sir this wrong solve by considering d ie assuming a gcd d such that dla

Comment: @Sanket The assumption used here is that there exist integers $u,v$ with $ua+vb=1$, which is equivalent to the OP assumption that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.